# get specific row number from table using lambda expression C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am using Entity FrameWork in c#. I need to get all the records from a table by id. I mean when I get `id = 1` I want to get the first 20 records. when I get `id = 2` I want to get records from the record 20 through 40 Etc.
the code:

```
int id = 1;
int prodId=50;

var prodList =  unitOfWork.ProdTBL.GetAll().ToList().Where(p => p.prodId.Equals(prodId));
```

I need that in the `prodList` will be only the first 20 records (because now `id=1`) if the id will be 2 I need `prodList` to contain the records[20] through 40.

**update**

I want not the write `GetAll()` because it takes a long time (there are a lot of records). But pre-get twenty records only, and not all the records and then get them twenty.

Comment: That is not an Id. One would expect that prodId is unique in a ProdTBL. Getting blocks is commonly known as paging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip `(id-1)*20` and then take `20` of them

```
var prodList =  unitOfWork.ProdTBL.Where(p => p.prodId.Equals(prodId))
         .Skip((id-1)* 20).Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: If GetAll() lives up to its name then this is very (very very) inefficient.

Comment: @HenkHolterman My concern was what user needed and actually i didn't look at the query itself. because I don't see the code, don't know what he is doing, ...

Comment: Is it possible to receive only twenty records in advance? Or you must do first getall and than to get only 20 records?

Comment: @rikush `.Take(20)` is just fine, it is just to avoid `GetAll()` .

Comment: @ashkan-mobayen-khiabani can you show me the code? I want not to write the GetAll() because it takes me long time (there are a lot of records)

Comment: @ashkan-mobayen-khiabani It still takes a long time, it seems that behind the scenes still goes through all the records and only then shows twenty of them

Comment: sorry, my mistake! I add .ToList() after the Where . And that's why he took a lot of time

Comment: @ashkan-mobayen-khiabani if I dont need to have condition - the where is Unnecessary. what is the sintax instead of the 'where'?